# Is joining to the result of a select (rather than an actual table) valid ANSI standard SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ansi-sql

Microsoft SQL Server allows this (using the Pubs database).

```
select 
    titles.title_id, title, TotalSales 
from 
    titles 
join 
    (select title_id, sum(qty) as TotalSales
     from sales 
     group by title_id) as ts on ts.title_id = titles.title_id
```

where the join is to the result of a select rather than an named table or view.

Is this valid ANSI standard syntax?

If it's not standard are there other well known databases that support it?

Comment: I'm asking if other well known databases which includes Oracle supports it.  It seemed logical to tag it with Oracle.

Comment: yes, that's valid ANSI SQL. It's called a derived table. To my knowledge all modern database support that.

Comment: You can verify ANSI SQL-2016 syntax compliance at https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is standard ANSI SQL, it's known as a *derived table* and is a building block of most SQL dialects.

In SQL it's perfectly valid to treat the result af a query as a table in its own right and reference it (with an appropriate alias) in any "parent" query.

It's supported by almost all RDBMS platforms.

I say almost as a caveat but I can't actually think of any currently supported platform that would not allow a derived table.